# why in Android 1024x600 is considered as mdpi?

Tags: android, android-screen-support, mdpi

I'm new with Android, and i don't know why android consider 1024x600 as mdpi, 
in my application i'm using some images, and there is no drawable folder for the 1024x600

Comment: You will have better luck using an Android developer support site [in some other language](http://www.andglobe.com), one which is more comfortable for you than English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display resolution (e.g. 1024x600) and screen density (e.g. mdpi) are [related but independent concepts](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms).

> **Screen size:**
>   Actual physical size, measured as the screen's diagonal.
>   For simplicity, Android groups all actual screen sizes into four generalized sizes: small, normal, large, and extra large.
>
> **Screen density:**
>   The quantity of pixels within a physical area of the screen; usually referred to as dpi (dots per inch). For example, a "low" density screen has fewer pixels within a given physical area, compared to a "normal" or "high" density screen.
>
> **Resolution:**
>   The total number of physical pixels on a screen. When adding support for multiple screens, applications do not work directly with resolution; applications should be concerned only with screen size and density, as specified by the generalized size and density groups.

Grossly oversimplifying, you generally provide different resources for different screen sizes when you want them to be different in phones and tablets (e.g. for layouts), and different resources for different densities so that the system doesn't need to scale them, which could cause artifacts (e.g. for images).